# makefile issues when using Eclipse C++ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, makefile, gsl

I'm getting "make: ***[diffusionWeightsTest] Error 1" and "recipe for target 'diffusionWeightsTest' failed" errors when trying to build a program in Eclipse's C++ IDE. If I open the makefile, the following code block is implicated with the error (specifically, the error is on @echo 'Building target: $@'):

```
diffusionWeightsTest: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++  -o "diffusionWeightsTest" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '
```

If I create a new HelloWorld C++ project and build it, it seems to work fine. Beyond linking the GSL libraries, I haven't done anything other than copy in my .C and .H code files (from my Windows machine, where I originally wrote them).

I'd like to do C++ development using Eclipse's IDE and the GSL library on a virtual Ubuntu Linux machine. I installed Oracle's JDK, the GSL library (following the INSTALL guidelines), and Eclipse's latest C++ IDE. In my program's properties, I linked the gsl and gslcblas libraries (right-click project name >> Properties >> C/C++ Build >> Settings >> GCC C++ Linker >> Libraries >> add both gslcblas and gsl to Libraries (-l) ) such that Eclipse seems to recognize those functions in the code.

Any ideas what might be causing this makefile error?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out, actually. Apparently, there's a particular order in how you link the GSL libraries to your project. You have to list "gsl" first and then list "gslcblas".

So, to clarify, after you've installed the GSL library (download the package from their website, extracted it, opened the terminal inside the GSL folder, ./configure, make, sudo make install), you have to link the gsl and gslcblas libraries to your Eclipse project. Right-click the project name in the Project Explorer in Eclipse >> Properties >> C/C++ Build >> Settings >> GCC C++ Linker >> Libraries >> add both gsl and gslcblas to Libraries (-l).

But you **must** put gsl first and then gslcblas. The order matters. You'll get the errors above otherwise.